# Can't get my php container to connect to the mysql container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm totally new to docker and I'm trying to create a LEMP stack with docker-compose. All my containers are running but I can't get my php container to connect to my mysql container. I have  a docker-compose.yml that looks like this:

```
version: '2'

services:
nginx:
image: evild/alpine-nginx:1.9.15-openssl
container_name: lemp_nginx
restart: always
links:
  - php:php
volumes:
  - ./html:/var/www/html/:ro
  - ./nginx/conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:ro
  - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro
ports:
  - 80:80
  - 443:443

php:
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile.php-fpm
container_name: lemp_php
restart: always
volumes:
  - ./html:/var/www/html
depends_on:
  - db
links:
  - db:db

db:
image: mariadb:latest
container_name: lemp_mariadb
restart: always
volumes:
  - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
environment:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wp
  MYSQL_DATABASE: wp
volumes:
db-data:
driver: local
```

Then in my ./html folder I created an index.php file with the following content to test the db connection:

```
<?php

$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'wp';
$dbhost = 'db';

$connect = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Unable to      Connect to '$dbhost'");

echo "Connected to DB!";
```

The result is the following:
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'172.18.0.3' (using password: YES) in /var/www/html/index.php on line 7
Unable to Connect to 'db'

Comment: $dbhost should be 'localhost' I guess?

Comment: Not working: "Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /var/www/html/index.php on line 7
Unable to Connect to 'localhost'"

It can't be localhost because the php container doesn't have a mysql running right?

Comment: Ok, I read your edit now. The access denied error means the connectivity work but there is/are some permission issue(s)

Comment: Are you able to connect it from your command line or some other mysql browser?

Comment: I tried with MySQL workbench. Exact same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. It was the following line:

```
environment: - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=wp
```

That didn't work, instead the root password was "password".

So when I connected to the mysql container and ran:

```
mysql -h localhost -p -u root wp
```

Using password "wp" didn't work, but password "password" worked.

So, it seems the env vars isn't working for mariadb. It also didn't create the wp wordpress at all.

Answer (score 0):

To get the IP of the any container run `docker inspect <container_name> | grep IPAddress`. With the IP you will be able to connect within other containers.

Comment: That commad tells me that mysql server is on ip 172.18.0.2 but using either $dbhost='db' or $dbhost='172.18.0.2' doesn't work. Still same error: Access denied for user 'root'@'172.18.0.3

Comment: If `$dbhost = '172.18.0.2'` and your error is `Access denied for user 'root'@'172.18.0.3`. Looks like you need to check again cos the IP has changed from 172.18.0.2 to 172.18.0.3 when executing the code. Looks like something else is changing your IP codewise. 
I will advice you to run `docker exec -it <container_id> bash` on the terminal. Replace the `container_id` with your mysql container_id. Test your db connection there with `mysql -h localhost -p -u root wp`

Comment: my php container has ip 172.18.0.3, and my mysql container has ip 172.18.0.2. Since its the php container trying to connect to mysql on 172.18.0.2 the error message seems right doesn't it? The php container seems to be able to try to connect but the mysql container responds with access denied because the request is comming from another address than localhost in this case root@172.18.0.3?

Comment: Found the problem. It was the following line:
environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=wp
That didn't work, instead the root password was "password". So when i connected to the mysql container and ran:
mysql -h localhost -p -u root wp. Using password "wp" didn't work but password "password" worked. So it seems the env vars isn't working for mariadb. It also didn't create the wp wordpress at all.

Comment: Nice, that feels odd.